# How to overwrite only files which are smaller using rsync

Tags: rsync

I try to use `rsync` to copy dirs recursively like so:

```
rsync -a /src/* /dst
```

- `/src` contains `sample.png (0.5MB)`
- `/dst` contains `sample.png (1MB)`

They both have the same timestamp. Now when I run the `rsync` command of course the `sample.png` with 1MB gets overwritten by the `sample.png` with 0.5MB which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to tell `rsync` that it should only copy files that are bigger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rsync` does not natively support this kind of transfer condition, but there is an option which *effectively* has the behaviour you want, although **it is not efficient** and sort of stretches what the option was intended for by quite a bit, **therefore use with caution and verify on non-critical test cases before production use**.

The option is called `--append-verify`.

To explain, I quote from the `rsync` manpage, and here first on the `--append` option:

> `--append`
>
> This  causes rsync to update a file by appending data onto the end of the file, which presumes that the data that already exists on the receiving side is identical with the start of the file on the sending side.  *If a file needs to be transferred  and its size on the receiver is the same or longer than the size on the sender, the file is skipped*.

In other words, the `--append` option assumes that, as the name implies, files on the source only ever change by adding to the end, and skips all files which are smaller on the source than on the destination so you will not overwrite a file on the destination with a smaller file.

Because I am not completely sure about the internal workings of that option,  and because of the implication that only the "additional" parts of the file (i.e. only the parts after the last byte present on the destination, regardless of whether the parts before are really the same) are actually transferred, I would recommend to

- use `--append-verify`, which, as the man-page states, includes the entire file content in the post-transfer verification process, and resends it if there are discrepancies in the first parts of the file (which the option *a priori* would consider as identical). In my understanding, this should ensure that even in the case that at first only the "additional" part is actually transferred, the verification will consider *the entire content* of the file, notice that the parts that would have been the same had your file really only "grown by appending" also differ, and resend the entire file, thus creating a correct copy of it. This of course means unnecessary data transfer and is the reason for my warning about this being non-efficient.
- only use this particular option on the file(s) where you need it, in your example the `sample.png`, thoroughly check that it *really* does what was intended, and copy all other files with "regular" `rsync` options.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. I guess for more complex conditions you'd just have to use one of the --backup options and then have a separate script go through /dst to compare new file vs. backup file and decide which to keep.

Comment: Yes, I think that this use of `rsync` stretches the specifications by quite a bit, and a real solution will need an external toolchain. It should do what the OP wants, but it is a dirty hack.

Comment: @AdminBee It did work for that specific case. I tried some other cases and it also does what I want to achieve. Simply: Don't copy src files with less size than dst files. Otherwise completely overwrite the file with src file. 
What is the risk when not doing it file by file? The logic doesn't change for me and the behaviour for all other files and folders was like normal `rsync`. Could not find any discrepancies in my test cases.

Comment: @MangoD Glad to hear that. If you consider the answer helpful, please consider accepting it so that others facing a similar problem can find it more easily. As to why I added (admittedly many) words of caution: although I did assume that it should work (otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it), I try to always err on the safe side and nag about testing before use in cases where I use options of a program in ways that possibly differ from the program author's intended use, because this might be what the program author didn't test in detail (I certainly know I am sloppy in that respect ...)